# Call a function before a modal dialog

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-dialog

I have a modal dialog with a form. I am closing the modal on clicking outside the modal using backdrop property. But when i do any changes in form i want to warn the user.

```
$("#dialog").modal({
  backdrop: true,
  keyboard: false,
  show: true,
});
```

and i used

```
$('#dialog').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
     var changed_data = $("#form").serialize();
     if(changed_data!=original_data){
        $('#dialog').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = "static";
     }
     else
     {
        $('#dialog').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = true;
     }
})
```

The above method is fired after closing the modal. I need to to warn the user about unsaved changes and make the dialog not to close

Comment: show your html code or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
if(changed_data!=original_data){
     $('#dialog').data('bs.modal').options.backdrop = "static";
     alert("warn user message");
     $('#dialog').modal('show');  //Show modal again
}
```